# How to convert output to a list

Tags: python

Below is the code for basic program that prints prime numbers in given range. I want prime numbers to be arranged in the list instead of just being printed one per line.

```
lower = int(input("Enter lower range: "))
upper = int(input("Enter upper range: "))

print("Prime numbers between", lower, "and", upper, "are:")

for num in range(lower, upper + 1):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                break
        else:
            print(num)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lower = int(input("Enter lower range: "))
upper = int(input("Enter upper range: "))
prime_list = list()
print("Prime numbers between", lower, "and", upper, "are:")

for num in range(lower, upper + 1):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
               break
        else:
            prime_list.append(num)
print(prime_list)
```

Create an empty list `prime_list = list()` and append the prime numbers to that list. Finally print the list `print(prime_list)`

Answer (score 0):

You should append to a list instead of printing the numbers:

```
lower = int(input("Enter lower range: "))
upper = int(input("Enter upper range: "))

print("Prime numbers between", lower, "and", upper, "are:")

prime_numbers = []

for num in range(lower, upper + 1):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                break
        else:
            prime_numbers.append(num)

print(prime_numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lower = int(input("Enter lower range: "))
upper = int(input("Enter upper range: "))
print("Prime numbers between", lower, "and", upper, "are:")

def get_primes():
    for num in range(lower, upper + 1):
        if num > 1:
            for i in range(2, num):
                if (num % i) == 0:
                        break
            else:
                yield num

print ', '.join([str(n) for n in get_primes()])
```